# Angular - download file as SafeResourceUrl

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the below method to get a file doc, pfd... from the backend. How can i download the file in this same method ?

```
loadFileUsingPOST(fileName: string): Observable<any> {
    const path = this.domain + `/load-file/${fileName}`;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', '*/*,application/xlsx,application/xls,application/xlsm');
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(path, { headers: headers, responseType: 'arraybuffer' as 'json' });
}


public getFile() {
  this.api.loadFileUsingPOST(this.fileName).subscribe((result: any) => {
     const blob = new Blob([result]);
     let fileUrl: SafeResourceUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a live demo with 2 methods for you:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blob-file-download-5m6erh?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Solution 1: Download from `<a> tag` on `fileUrl: SafeResourceUrl`. You set `fileUrl` and `fileName`.

```
<a [href]="fileUrl" [download]="fileName">Download file</a>
```

Solution 2: Download from `Blob` by custom `blob extension`.

```
declare global {
  interface Blob {
    saveFile(fileName: string): void;
  }
}
Blob.prototype.saveFile = function (fileName: string) {
  if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(this, fileName);
  } else {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(this);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    }, 0);
  }
};
```

You extension your Blob extension like the above, and then you just need to import it into where you want to use. Easy to use: `blobResponse.saveFile(fileName);`